# Find most recently edited row in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

In Access VBA, is it possible to find the most recently edited row (Record) in a table?

Example below would be ID 3 as the most recently edited row

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Access 2010 you can use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to automatically update a Date/Time field in your table. For example, if you add a Date/Time field named [LastUpdated] then the following macro will update that field whenever a record is inserted or updated:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

The advantage of this approach is that it takes place at the table level so the [LastUpdated] field is updated regardless of how the record is inserted or modified. (That is, you don't need to rely on form code to update the field.)

Comment: Fantastic I'll give this a go

Answer (score 0):

You can add a time stamp field to your table and create a form based on the table. When shown as a table, the form will give you the same functionality as the table itself, but you will be able to set an event `AfterUpdate` The event can then (over)write the time stamp for that record. You can hide the time stamp control on the form if you like, or set `Enabled=False`